# Advanced Search vb.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

I Have advanced search for that is containing combobox1,combobox2,combobox3 I searched for a way to make search in database. 
If I select combobox1 and not select combobox2 and combobox3 and if I select combobox2 and not select combobox1 and combobox3 also same in combobox3 and in select all comboboxs I did not found a solution , do I need to make more than SqlCommand for each case ? or there is a easy way to do this I tried to make SqlCommand

```
 Public Sub Load_Main(ByVal projectid As Integer, ByVal pdocid As Integer, ByVal depid As Integer)
    main_Datatable.Clear()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select * from main where projectid=@projectid and pdocid=@pdocid and depid=@depid", DBConnection)

    cmd.Parameters.Add("projectid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = projectid
    cmd.Parameters.Add("pdocid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = pdocid
    cmd.Parameters.Add("depid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = depid
    DBConnection.Open()
    main_Datatable.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    DBConnection.Close()
    cmd = Nothing

End Sub

Load_Main(project_combo.SelectedValue, doc_combo.SelectedValue, Depart_combo.SelectedValue)
```

But if I did not select the other combobox just one it not work

Comment: Build your sql statement, and add parameters, only for the values that aren't o (or null).

Comment: Use a stored procedure then you can use dynamic sql or from code use if conditions to build your sql; pick one.

Comment: Also you should wrap your commands in using statements so they get properly disposed of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it, without changing too much code, assuming a 0 value means nothing was selected in the combo box:

```
Public Sub Load_Main(ByVal projectid As Integer, ByVal pdocid As Integer, ByVal depid As Integer)
    main_Datatable.Clear()
    Dim query as string
    query = "select * " & _
            "from main " & _
            "where projectid = ISNULL(NULLIF(@projectid, 0), projectid) " & _
            "and pdocid = ISNULL(NULLIF(@pdocid, 0), pdocid) " & _
            "and depid = ISNULL(NULLIF(@depid, 0), depid) "
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(query, DBConnection)

    cmd.Parameters.Add("projectid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = projectid
    cmd.Parameters.Add("pdocid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = pdocid
    cmd.Parameters.Add("depid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = depid
    DBConnection.Open()
    main_Datatable.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    DBConnection.Close()
    cmd = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: If I add new 2 combobox the first one with contain {All,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} and the second contains {All,Submitted,Approved,Rejected} How to add it to the search

Comment: same thing - just replace the `0` with `All` - `and column = ISNULL(NULLIF(@parameter, 'All'), column)`

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub Load_Main(ByVal projectid As Integer, ByVal pdocid As Integer, ByVal depid As Integer)
    main_Datatable.Clear()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select * from main where (@projectid IS NULL OR projectid=@projectid) and (@pdocid IS NULL OR pdocid=@pdocid) and (@depid IS NULL OR depid=@depid)", DBConnection)

    cmd.Parameters.Add("projectid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = If(projectid = 0, CObj(DBNull.Value), projectid)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("pdocid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = If(pdocid = 0, CObj(DBNull.Value), pdocid)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("depid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = If(depid = 0, CObj(DBNull.Value), depid)
    DBConnection.Open()
    main_Datatable.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    DBConnection.Close()
    cmd = Nothing

End Sub
```

If you set a parameter to null then it is effectively ignored because it matches every record. Since your's are being passed in as integers, set it to 0 (or some other integer value that would never be used like -1) if you want it ignored in your SQL clause.

And you should use a Using statement instead.

Comment: If I add new 2 combobox the first one with contain {All,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} and the second contains {All,Submitted,Approved,Rejected} How to add it to the search

Comment: @MichaelRaouf I see you already got an answer from Zohar since our answers are essentially identical. In my version you'd do something like `cmd.Parameters.Add("status", SqlDbType.varchar).Value = If(status = 'All', CObj(DBNull.Value), status)`